# How can I verify my form while redirecting to a separate page?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation, redirect

So I'm creating a form that uses the values entered to create a PDF. Now, the php that I'm using to do this is already completed from another person. Currently everything works great, except once you complete the form it redirects you to the site listed in action="..."

```
<form action="http://www.otherdomain.com/action.php" method="post" name="application" target='_blank' onsubmit="return validateform(this);">
```

That is what the code looks like. I would like to have the code redirect to my own 'success' page rather than the otherdomain.com success page, except I can't copy the PHP into my own page because I am using wordpress and there isn't a way to create a page with a .php ending, so the action needs to stay as-is.

Sorry if I'm seeming kind of vague, I don't know much about php or javascript and I'm having troubles putting my thoughts into words.

Comment: The action parameter is not a "redirect", it is where to POST the data.  The result of the POST is what you're interpreting as a "redirect".

Comment: Have you considered using `$.ajax({});` to get around this problem? It can be useful in situations like these

Comment: You can try using the php page in an `<iframe>` on your own page but without being able to change their page you can't do much redirecting on their page.

Comment: @SteveH. So what would happen if I changed post to get? Is there any easy way that I can click 'submit' and it takes me to my own site rather than to the external one?

Comment: @user2411114 It wouldn't make a difference.  The user will attach a file to the form in the browser and then submit the form.  This causes the contents of the file to be sent to the server location mentioned in the "action" attribute.  The server processes the file, then returns a page as the result.  It sounds like you want the other server to process the file, but then YOU want to show the result page.  Without modifying the server code you can't do this.  If you can change the form to post to YOUR server, you will need to process the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this request within your server, using PHP extension named `curl` to achieve this.

Basically, from you own website, the script will make another request based on the one you sent with de form, get the response and then redirect to the disired page.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Will it conflict with the way Wordpress creates it's pages? Is there an easier way where I can just add something that redirects me to my site instead of the external one?

Comment: If you have no control over the external site, so, you can't do this. And no, there will be no conflict with Wordpress.